# How to get IP address of WCF web service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services

When calling a WCF web service from a C# client (instance of System.ServiceModel.ClientBase<>)  how can I get the IP address of the server I'm connected to?

Context: we've setup a web farm for some WCF services and I need to know which specific server I'm connected to when an exception occurs.

Comment: Web farm is hidden by load balancer so I expect you can't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add this to your catch:

```
    IPHostEntry heserver = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
    IPAddress curAdd = heserver.AddressList[0];
    curAdd.ToString();
```

Comment: You would have to add this to the server, and have it return its own IP through the fault contract or in logging, right? You didn't really specify.

Comment: I think the original message had some code or something and he wanted to send the IP address in his error message - which was sent from the catch.  With that said, you would add this to our WCF service in a catch which would return information however you do that.  We use a result object which has an error message, I would just add to that error message the IP address.

Answer (score 1):

Your load balancer presumably is hiding the specific web server from you.

The usual strategy is to log errors per-server and use a log aggregator of some sort for operations to monitor all servers.

If your client code really needs to know the specific server, consider returning that information as part of the exception.  After all, the server knows it's own identity.

Comment: It's doing DNS round robin. And sometimes the error is from the client side in that it can't connect to the server.

Comment: If the client can't connect to the server, then there is no IP address to return :)  Your only hope then is to trace the path with Wireshark: http://www.wireshark.org/download.html