# How to access info about where the WCF service is deployed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis-7, hosting

I have one WCF service deployed in multiple websites hosted in IIS7 and sometimes (development environemnt) in VS2010.

Often multiple instances are connected to the same database and usually its not a problem as its read-only access, but sometimes (like in logging) I need to uniquely identify instance of the service accessing DB.

Currently I do it by putting special attribute in web.config which I'll later use as a part of primary key, but I do feel its not ideal solution.

I thought about site-name in case its hosted in IIS and machine name + port if its hosted from VS2010.

And here comes the question: How to access info about where the WCF service is deployed and how to do it programmatically from inside of deployed service in c#? Is it at all possible?

Thank you for your suggestions.
Michal

Answer (score 0):

The other day there was a question about how to get the IP address of the WCF server, for logging. This topic might help: [How to get IP address of WCF web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383333/how-to-get-ip-address-of-wcf-web-service/5383475#5383475)

---

You could also determine if you are running in IIS by finding out what process your app is being run from using `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess()`, and see if it is "w3svc.exe", which is what the IIS app pool runs as.

Comment: Unfortunately IP is not enough, because many services may be using the same IP, or there could be one VM with multiple IP addresses, but thank you for the idea about processes that will be useful to distinguish between VS and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, and I may not, you would like to know were on the server the actual instance is deployed.

If this is the case you can use something like:

```
 (string)AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetData("APPBASE")
```

Or I believe this will also work:

```
  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
```

Using reflection on the assembly or process itself will not work because the running process is the host (IIS, IISExpress, etc), but the two methods I specified should give you the location of the service itself for hosted apps.